# Does 'Stoichiometry' refer to the mole ratio of atoms in compounds and the mole ratio of compounds involved in chemical reactions?

Tags: stoichiometry

For my intro to chemistry class, I was asked to answer whether 'stoichiometry' refers to the mole ratio of atoms in compounds and the mole ratio of compounds involved in chemical reactions?

To the best of my knowledge those ratios are an essential part of stoichiometry, but stoichiometry is a discipline, and not a ratio, so the answer would be false.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right -- stoichiometry is a field which uses these numbers and the relationships between reactants and products, but not the numbers itself. The mole ratio is just the mole ratio, whereas stoichiometry is the entire discipline of using mole ratios *to calculate* relative quantities of reactants and products in reactions.